# I can't figure out why my if else statement is terminating when asking for cin

Tags: c++

I am new here. I am trying to write a program that gives you a secondary color when you input two primary colors. I have it setup so that if a user enters two of the same primary colors it has you re enter two different primary colors but after they re enter colors for some reason the program terminates instead of runs through the other else if statements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    string myColor1, myColor2;

    cout << "Enter two primary colors (Ex. red blue): ";
    cin >> myColor1 >> myColor2;

    if (myColor1 == "purple" || myColor2 == "purple") {
        cout << "One or both of the colors you selected are not primary, please select a primary color: ";
        cin >> myColor1, myColor2;
    }

    else if (myColor1 == "orange" || myColor2 == "orange") {
        cout << "One or both of the colors you selected are not primary, please select a primary color: ";
        cin >> myColor1, myColor2;
    }

    else if (myColor1 == "green" || myColor2 == "green") {
        cout << "One or both of the colors you selected are not primary, please select a primary color: ";
        cin >> myColor1, myColor2;
    }

    else if (myColor1 == "red" && myColor2 == "red") {
        cout << "Both the colors you selected are primary. Please select two different primary colors: ";
        cin >> myColor1, myColor2;
    }

    else if (myColor1 == "yellow" && myColor2 == "yellow") {
        cout << "Both the colors you selected are primary. Please select two different primary colors: ";
        cin >> myColor1, myColor2;
    }

    else if (myColor1 == "blue" && myColor2 == "blue") {
        cout << "Both the colors you selected are primary. Please select two different primary colors: ";
        cin >> myColor1, myColor2;
    }

    else if (((myColor1 == "red") && (myColor2 == "blue")) || ((myColor1 == "blue") && (myColor2 == "red"))) {
        cout << "Red and Blue = Purple" << endl;
    }

    else if (((myColor1 == "red") && (myColor2 == "yellow")) || ((myColor1 == "yellow") && (myColor2 == "red"))) {
        cout << "Red and Yellow = Orange" << endl;
    }

    else if (((myColor1 == "Blue") && (myColor2 == "Yellow")) || ((myColor1 == "Yellow") && (myColor2 == "Blue"))) {
        cout << "Blue and Yellow = Green" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't experience "terminating", what do you mean?
When I write yellow yellow for example it asks again, and no matter what you write it'll finish the program

Comment: Only one else-if branch will ever be executed. For example, if you enter the first branch, the program will ask for a new color and then skip all other branches and thus immediately terminate.

Comment: Hi please try putting a loop. So that after re entering control can go back and check other if else

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Do you not understand why it terminates? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @David Schwartz sorry I wasn't clear. I was wondering why it was terminating but idmean answered. Thanks for reading through my code and giving me some of your time though. I'll be more clear with posts in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code, that is why you are not able to see the correct results:

The `if` statements are implemented in a wrong way. You have used initially an `if` statement and then used `else if`. The thing is that if you enter the colour purple twice, it checks it the first time, notices the two colours are the same, prompts a message, asks for input, and then goes to `return 0` hence exiting the program.

What you actually need to do is:

Replace your `else-if` sequence in the following manner-

First, `if` statement and followed by 5 `if` (to check for the same colours) and then in the next set of conditionals, make it `if` followed by 2 `else if` statements.

One thing I would like to tell you is that you have used too many `if` statements to check if the colours are same. Rather than checking for each and every colour, you can check if the two strings are equal, and if they are equal, ask the user for a different colours.

Hence, an improved version of this code can be:

```
string myColor1, myColor2;

cout << "Enter two primary colors (Ex. red blue): ";
cin >> myColor1 >> myColor2;

if(myColor1.compare(myColor2)==0)
  {
     cout<<"same colours, enter again:";
     cin>>myColor1>>myColor2;
  }

if (((myColor1 == "red") && (myColor2 == "blue")) || ((myColor1 == "blue") && (myColor2 == "red"))) 
    cout << "Red and Blue = Purple" << endl;

else if (((myColor1 == "red") && (myColor2 == "yellow")) || ((myColor1 == "yellow") && (myColor2 == "red")))
    cout << "Red and Yellow = Orange" << endl;


else if (((myColor1 == "blue") && (myColor2 == "yellow")) || ((myColor1 == "yellow") && (myColor2 == "blue")))
    cout << "Blue and Yellow = Green" << endl;

return 0;
```

Also, keep in mind to enter the colours in lower-case because your program checks for colours only in lower-case. Enjoy programming and C++! :)

Best.

Comment: I had stayed up all night figuring it out and I had finally figured it out but the changes you wrote shorten the program a ton and do pretty much the same thing to what I wrote which is awesome! Thanks so much!!! :)

Comment: No worries mate! I can totally understand how complex it must’ve become for you! Also, just mark your question as answered, so people know it’s been solved! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you. I suggest that you should use do-while loop with this program 
I'm a beginner by the way 
hope the best
here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
do
{
    string myColor1,myColor2;

    cout << "Enter two primary colors (Ex. red blue): ";
    cin >> myColor1 >> myColor2;

    if (myColor1 == "purple" || myColor2 == "purple") 
    {
        cout << "One or both of the colors you selected are not primary, please select a primary color: ";
    }

    else if (myColor1 == "orange" || myColor2 == "orange")
    {
        cout << "One or both of the colors you selected are not primary, please select a primary color: ";
    }

    else if (myColor1 == "green" || myColor2 == "green") 
    {
        cout << "One or both of the colors you selected are not primary, please select a primary color: ";
    }

    else if (myColor1 == "red" && myColor2 == "red") 
    {
        cout << "Both the colors you selected are primary. Please select two different primary colors: ";
    }

    else if (myColor1 == "yellow" && myColor2 == "yellow")
    {
        cout << "Both the colors you selected are primary. Please select two different primary colors: ";
    }

    else if (myColor1 == "blue" && myColor2 == "blue")
    {
        cout << "Both the colors you selected are primary. Please select two different primary colors: ";
    }

    else if (((myColor1 == "red") && (myColor2 == "blue")) || ((myColor1 == "blue") && (myColor2 == "red")))
    {
        cout << "Red and Blue = Purple" << endl;
    }

    else if (((myColor1 == "red") && (myColor2 == "yellow")) || ((myColor1 == "yellow") && (myColor2 == "red"))) 
    {
        cout << "Red and Yellow = Orange" << endl;
    }

    else if (((myColor1 == "Blue") && (myColor2 == "Yellow")) || ((myColor1 == "Yellow") && (myColor2 == "Blue"))) 
    {
        cout << "Blue and Yellow = Green" << endl;
    }
}while (true);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I'd be happy to upvote this, if you corrected the formatting a bit.

Comment: Thanks so much for the post!

Answer (score 1):

The program @rasengan__ wrote is way shorter and does pretty much the same thing but this is what I had come up with last night on my own in case anyone was wondering.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
string myColor1, myColor2;

here:
cout << "Enter two primary colors (Ex. red blue): ";
cin >> myColor1 >> myColor2;

if (myColor1 == "purple" || myColor2 == "purple") {
    cout << "One or both of the colors you selected are not primary, please select a primary color" << endl;
    goto here;
}

else if (myColor1 == "orange" || myColor2 == "orange") {
    cout << "One or both of the colors you selected are not primary, please select a primary color" << endl;
    goto here;
}

else if (myColor1 == "green" || myColor2 == "green") {
    cout << "One or both of the colors you selected are not primary, please select a primary color" << endl;
    goto here;
}

else if (myColor1 == "red" && myColor2 == "red") {
    cout << "Both the colors you selected are primary. Please select two different primary colors" << endl;
    goto here;
}

else if (myColor1 == "yellow" && myColor2 == "yellow") {
    cout << "Both the colors you selected are primary. Please select two different primary colors" << endl;
    goto here;
}

else if (myColor1 == "blue" && myColor2 == "blue") {
    cout << "Both the colors you selected are primary. Please select two different primary colors" << endl;
    goto here;
}

else if (((myColor1 == "red") && (myColor2 == "blue")) || ((myColor1 == "blue") && (myColor2 == "red"))) {
    cout << "Red and Blue = Purple" << endl;
}

else if (((myColor1 == "red") && (myColor2 == "yellow")) || ((myColor1 == "yellow") && (myColor2 == "red"))) {
    cout << "Red and Yellow = Orange" << endl;
}

else if (((myColor1 == "Blue") && (myColor2 == "Yellow")) || ((myColor1 == "Yellow") && (myColor2 == "Blue"))) {
    cout << "Blue and Yellow = Green" << endl;
}


return 0;
}
```